# How to practice effectively when your time is limited

Tags: practice

<sup>This is a theoretical question based on things I hear a lot</sup>

Often I hear things such as "I'm really busy and don't always have time to practice". The feedback I usually give is for a practice session that's maybe around 10-20 minutes long, break a song you are working on into chunks and work on one specific chunk, and maybe one specific idea within that chunk (e.g. rhythm, articulation, counting).

I'm curious is there any other feedback I can give that can help people practice more efficiently and effectively to make the most of their time? For context, these are usually middle schoolers that I talk with. I've often heard in the various circles that I am in that the best way to get good at some concept in music is just to devote a lot of time to it and work with it until you acquire a better understanding, but that does not always work for some people.

What are good ways to practice well for people who dont always have a lot of time?

Comment: In so-called "first-world countries", people (including kids) can find time to practice if they _want_ to. Such comments most often mean that for them many other things have higher priority. Oop, but then that does also spill over into limited interest in optimizing practice time. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett This is a valuable point. Thank you, and I will definitely shift my outlook with this point.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is just one of many related questions posted on this topic. For example, [Maximizing Practice Time](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/15462/70803). Some are instrument specific, such as [How to practice piano more efficiently and effectively?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/30012/70803).

Comment: A 10-minute practice session (or even 20) doesn't let you do much, but one of my big talking points is that they're better than nothing. And [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/58610/practice-for-skill-maintenance-with-busy-life) is a big part of the puzzle: practice techniques don't do any good if you never actually practice.